# Is there a way to design this "static class" so that it is thread-safe?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, thread-safety

I have a class with all methods static, like this:

```
class A { 
public:
   static std::string getA() { GlobalData::alfa; }
   static std::string sum(int x, int y) { ... }

   static int convert() { ... }

};
```

I need that A could be thread-safe. Whitch is the better design for do that? I need to convert all methods in a non-static method like this?

```
class B { 
public:
   std::string getA() { g.alfa; }
   std::string sum(int x, int y) { ... }
   int convert() { ... }

private:
   GlobalData g;
};
```

Consider that GlobalData is a simple POD like this:

```
struct GlobalData
{
   static std::string foo;
   static int bar;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Why not use free functions instead?

Comment: `B` is obviously implicitly threadsafe ASSUMING there is an instance of `B` per thread. If there is a single `B`, you haven't improved anything.

Comment: Thread safety is not something you can just add in. It requires design. With no indication of what resources these functions use, it's impossible to say what steps could make then thread-safe. But changing them from static functions to member functions won't do it.

Comment: how do you plan to use these? What is `GlobalData`?

Comment: I forgot to say that **GlobalData** is a plain structor with all members data static

Comment: @TonyTheLion you suggest to use **A** as namespace?

Comment: if you need to clarify something, please do it in the question directly.

Comment: In order to guarantee thread-safety, you have to look at what data each method will be writing to, and also look at any other code that might be reading that same data.  Then you have to figure out how you're going to avoid the possibility of thread A reading that data while thread B is in the middle of writing to it.  Typically this is done by adding mutexes to serialize access to the data, but it's also sometimes possible to reorganize the data's structure to avoid hazards instead.  In any case, declaring methods static vs non-static is only tangentially related to the real task at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the original layout of class `A`, or even change it to a namespace instead, but you will have to define the `GlobalData` struct as thread local storage, if the data it contains must be specific to each thread:

```
 struct GlobalData {
    static thread_local std::string alfa;
    // other members here
};
```

You will probably need to call a function to initialize the data as needed for each thread.

Note that you could also turn that struct into a namespace if all the members have been defined `static`:

```
namespace GlobalData {
    thread_local std::string alfa;
    // etc.
}

namespace A {
   std::string getA() { return GlobalData::alfa; }
   std::string sum(int x, int y) { /* ... */ }

   int convert() { /* ... */ }
}
```

which improves your code readability.

The same rule should apply for any piece of data of global scope in your original code which must become thread specific.

Answer (score 1):

A better design would be to not have A use a static implementation at all. This would mean you create an A instance and use it in client code through dependency injection.

Then, you can implement the RW access to A's data, using standard synchronization primitives.

Since your A has static state and A is not an injected dependency, the code using A internally would be synchronized on the synchronization primitives you want to add in A's implementation. This introduces potential deadlocks that are completely invisible from client code, that could be difficult to find and diagnose (depending on the complexity of the interactions of client code of A).